# elegant way to extract a certain member from a list of objects

Tags: c++

I have a container with elements of some arbitrary structure/class.
Is there an elegant way to extract a single property (e.g. member or member.function) into a own array (e.g. to pass it to another algorithm)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    struct A{
      int n;
      int B()const;
    };

    std::vector<A>   manyOfA{{1,1}, {2,2},{3,3}};
    std::vector<int> allNs;

    // is there a standard way to do this kind of extraction?
    for(const auto& a:manyOfA){
      allNs.push_back(a.n);
      // or maybe allNs.push_back(a.B());
    };

    std::cout << "result Vector: ";
    for(const auto& n: allNs){
      std::cout << n << ", ";
    };
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to apply a function to every element of an iterator range and collect the results in a result range. In you case, the result range can be a `std::back_inserter` iterator. This is a special iterator that calls `v.push_back` on a given container when assigning a value.

```
std::vector<A>   manyOfA{{1,1}, {2,2},{3,3}};
std::vector<int> allNs;

std::transform(manyOfA.begin(), manyOfA.end(), std::back_inserter(allNs), [](A const& a) {return a.n;});
```

Or even better with a range library, e.g. boost.range. This will save the creation of a new vector just to hold the values of `a.n`:

```
template <typename RangeType>
void doSomethingWithRange(const RangeType &range) { ... }

auto allNs = manyOfA | transformed([](A const& a) {return a.n;});
doSomethingWithRange(allNs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you could also use [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)

```
for_each(begin(manyOfA), end(manyOfA), [&](auto a) { allNs.emplace_back(a.n); });
```